# Verificar índice em dict

Tags: python

Tenho uma função que me retorna 2 resultados, `None` ou `dict` porém estou tentando verificar se uma chave especifica esta no resultado dessa função.

```
def get_language(card):
if not card.foreign_names == None:
    for c in card.foreign_names:
        if c['language'].lower().startswith('Portuguese'.lower()):
            return c
return None
```

Quando a função retorna um `dict` eu consigo facilmente verificar a chave da seguinte maneira:

```
result = get_language(card)
'my_key' in result
```

Porém se a função retornar `None` eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Este erro é gerado devido a uma tentativa de comparação usando um `if` inline:

```
a = x if 'my_key' in result else None
```

Em meu computador eu consigo realizar esta tarefa mesmo com `None` porém eu meu notebook não, isso tem haver com a versão do python? e como posso resolver isso?

> Python 3.5.2

Comment: Qual é a opereção que estás a tentar fazer depois? quando te dá esse erro?

Comment: @Miguel eu pego o resultado e tento fazer uma comparação com o `if` inline, `a = x if 'my_key' in result else None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na comparação verifica primeiro se result é None, e só depois se a chave existe:

```
result = None
a = result['my_key'] if result is not None and 'my_key' in result else None
print(a) # None
```

...

```
result = {'my_key': 123}
a = result['my_key'] if result is not None and 'my_key' in result else None
print(a) # 123
```

Também podias remediar facilmente e manter a condição como a tens, se em vez de `None` a tua função retornar um dicionário vazio, `return {}`:

```
result = {}
a = result['my_key'] if 'my_key' in result else None
print(a) # None
```

Comment: recebo o mesmo erro, pois a comparação `result is not None` não pode ser iterável.

Comment: Vou remediar @RafaelAcioly

Comment: não fiz nenhuma iteração depois deste `if`

Comment: Esse erro é te dado dentro da função que puseste no teu c+odigo? @RafaelAcioly

Comment: Não, o erro é dado fora da função, logo quando realizo a comparação com o `if`

Comment: Já sei porque é... Vou colocar na resposta @RafaelAcioly

Comment: O ultimo código que você colocou é exatamente o que eu publiquei na pergunta, e não funciona.

Comment: @RafaelAcioly tens de fazer a tua função retornar um dict vazio em vez de None, eu expliquei em cima do codigo